# "creating" a key similar to the Fn key on a computer

Tags: keyboard, fn-key

I recently switched from a laptop to a computer and I had an Fn key and I really liked it (Being able to control the volume was really useful) and I was wondering if there was a way to add that key on my computer (like a program to replace one of my keys and make it work like the Fn key)

Is this possible?

Comment: Fn kicks in before the composite key command even reaches the OS; it sends a different 'key'

Comment: Lots of desktop keyboards have volume buttons (and being less space constrained, don't need to double up functions using a Fn key).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So this is a bit of a tricky question as fn key functions do vary from laptop to laptop and usually are processed though a special driver which takes them and turns them in to the commands you used. That being said you can, essentially, create macros for each key function you want to have (and even add more that may not have existed on your keyboard before).

I would recommend reading up on AutoHotkey http://www.autohotkey.com/ and then looking for some preexisting key scripts out there for creating hotkeys to modify volume/brightness/media controls, etc.

It'll take a bit of reading to get how it works but there should be plenty of scripts out there for you and you can also make your own!

Comment: I tried it and it worked, thanks! here's the script I made:  !Up::  
Send {Volume_Up}  
return  
  
!Down::  
Send {Volume_Down}  
return

Comment: Fantastic! Glad it worked!